# What is this game with 16 pegs and 36 spools to fit on them?

Tags: identify-this-game

This board has 36 spools that fit on 16 pegs or sticks. 
It looks like it might be 3D checkers or something like that.
Interested in the name and how to play.

[image: Hand made board game!]

Someone took a lot of time making this really nice board game and I would like to use it properly.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! I've removed the signature from the end of your question, since we tend to do away with salutations and signatures here - your question is already signed with your user card beneath it after all.

Answer (score 6):

This looks a version of a game I used to own called **Score Four**. It is essentially the classic Connect 4 game, but in three dimensions instead of two.

It plays exactly as you would imagine

- players take turns adding pieces of their color onto pegs
- the first player to create a line of 4 in any direction (vertical, horizontal, diagonal) wins

It is considerably more interesting than Connect 4

http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3656/score-four

Answer (score 5):

I had the chance to play this game before: it's a 3D version of the classic game Connect 4 and as far as I know the same rules apply.

Although it looks very cool, in my humble opinion there are too many possibilities and it's far less fun than the 2D version. I'm not sure if it's patented and/or if there are "official" rules.